# How to put array in an I18n in html.erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am working with a t('footer.card.type.**name**') where I want to replace **name** with the array list. t('footer.card.type.**name**') by the way, is to show different languages in different I18n.

Currently I am stuck with placing |type| into t('footer.card_type.%{type}'). This I am sure it does not work. I am just experimenting on ways to making it work.

```
      <%= link_to t('footer.card_type.all'), credit_cards_path %>
      <% ['cash_back', 'islamic', 'petrol', 'reward', 'travel', 'no_annual_fee', 'premium', 'balance_transfer', 'promo'].each do |type| %>
        <%= link_to t('footer.card_type.%{type}'), credit_card_type_path(sub_type: type.gsub('_','-')) %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: I currently do not have access to rails project, so can't test it, may be you can try `'footer.card_type.' + type`?

Comment: Hey Askhat, thanks for answering. The `'footer.card_type.'+type` simply returns the translation for `'footer.card_type' + the items in the array`, but not the accurate translation itself. I have worked it out by adding `.concat(type)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around by adding **.concat(type)** after the **t('footer.card_type.')**. It successfully returns the translation of both languages. Hope this code can help someone.

```
   <% ['cash_back', 'islamic', 'petrol', 'reward', 'travel', 'no_annual_fee', 'premium', 'balance_transfer', 'promo'].each do |type| %>
        <%= link_to t('footer.card_type.'.concat(type)), credit_card_type_path(sub_type: type.gsub('_','-')) %>
   <% end %>
```